# return array of pointers from an array in Go

Tags: pointers, struct, go, slice

Just so you know, I am quite new to Go.

I have been trying to make a function like this:

```
func PointersOf(slice []AnyType) []*AnyType{
    //create an slice of pointers to the elements of the slice parameter
}
```

It is like doing `&slice[idx]` for all elements in the slice, but I am having trouble with how to type my parameters and return type, as well as how to create the slice itself.

This method needs to work for slices of built-in types, as well as for slices of structs and slices of pointers to built-in types/structs

After invoking this function it would be preferable if I don't have to cast the pointer slice

---

**Edit:**
The reason why I need this method is to have a generic way to use the elements of an array in a for ... range loop, in stead of using copies of that element. Consider:

```
type SomeStruct struct {
    x int
}

func main() {
    strSlice := make([]SomeStruct, 5)
    for _, elem := range strSlice {
        elem.x = 5
    }
}
```

This Doesn't work, because elem is a copy of the strSlice element.

```
type SomeStruct struct {
    x int
}

func main() {
    strSlice := make([]SomeStruct, 5)
    for _, elem := range PointersOf(strSlice) {
        (*elem).x = 5
    }
}
```

This however should work, since you only copy the pointer that points to an element in the original array.

Comment: You can't; Go types are invariant, and there are no generics. You create a slice of the type you need when you need it. Can you give an example why you would need this?

Comment: Perhaps you should first try to write such a function and make it work for a slice of `integers` only, for example. Then your `AnyType` should be an empty interface (`interface{}`) i guess, in case you want to support different types. Also can you show us a bit code, so that we can specifically help with what you're having problems.

Comment: I am trying to make this because the `for ... range` returns a copy of the elements in the given slice.  If I want to change my elements I'd normally need to use a normal for loop and fetch the element from the index `e = &slice[idx]`. It would however be easier if I could get the pointer array and use the elements by reference

Comment: @coolcat007: this is why `for ... range` returns an index as the first parameter, so you can index into your slice instead of making a copy. http://play.golang.org/p/f5ZY3-npaB

Comment: @JimB Yes, I know that, but having to get the element from the original array every time you use it, or in every `for ... range` loop having to type `elem = &slice[idx]` gets old really fast. This PointerOf function is already a headache, where I'd really like to see a `for ... &range` loop in the language by default

Comment: Go strives to never have hidden complexity, and your conversion requires an extra allocation and an O(n) copy. If you need to have a pointer to a value, you should always start with a pointer, i.e. your slice should be `[]*SomeStruct` from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code to loop through a slice of structs setting a field. There's no need to create a slice of pointers.

```
type SomeStruct struct {
  x int
}

func main() {
  strSlice := make([]SomeStruct, 5)
  for i := range strSlice {
    strSlice[i].x = 5
  }
}
```

<kbd>[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/f5ZY3-npaB)</kbd>

Here's the proposed PointersOf function:

```
func PointersOf(v interface{}) interface{} {
  in := reflect.ValueOf(v)
  out := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(reflect.PtrTo(in.Type().Elem())), in.Len(), in.Len())
  for i := 0; i < in.Len(); i++ {
    out.Index(i).Set(in.Index(i).Addr())
  }
  return out.Interface()
}
```

and here's how to use it:

```
for _, elem := range PointersOf(strSlice).([]*SomeStruct) {
    elem.x = 5
}
```

<kbd>[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/zogM3dYj4R)</kbd>